# Programmatically start exe on Azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, exe

Is there a way to tell an Azure VM to run an exe file from a .NET program?
I can start up some VMs in my scale set from an F# program. But how do I tell the VMs to actually start doing something? I.e. run my program?

Here I am trying to fire up 'MyProgram.exe' from a mapped network drive. I get the error

> Azure.RequestFailedException: 'The entity was not found in this Azure
> location. Status: 404 (Not Found) ErrorCode: NotFound

I can't find much documentation on this. I am certainly using RunCommand wrong, but I am not sure how to do it correctly.

````
let vms =
    vmss.GetVirtualMachineScaleSetVms()
    |> Seq.cast<VirtualMachineScaleSetVmResource>
    |> List.ofSeq
let powerOn =
    vms
    |> List.map (fun vm -> vm.PowerOn(Azure.WaitUntil.Started))
powerOn |> List.iter (fun op -> op.WaitForCompletionResponse() |> ignore)

vms
|> List.iteri (fun i vm ->
    let name = "Machine"+i.ToString()
    let command = Models.RunCommandInput("& 'S:\\MyProgram.exe' "+name)
    vm.RunCommand(Azure.WaitUntil.Completed, command) |> ignore
)

vmss.Deallocate(Azure.WaitUntil.Completed) |> ignore```
````

Comment: Depending on what you actually want to achieve, maybe Batch is a better route for you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-run-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct way to run an exe:

```
let command = Models.RunCommandInput("RunPowerShellScript")
command.Script.Add("& 'S:\\MyProgram.exe' "+name)
```

However as silent commented, Batch looks like it's set up to achieve what I'm trying to do.